# Dual Email Delivery. Google and BlueHost MX

Tags: email, hosting

How can I set up dual email delivery? 
I use google for business. It can get costly to add many users. I want my main users to have these tools, for others I could use a regular email hosting solution. I currently have bluehost and am looking for a way to make some email accounts work here, while in google have up to 5 accounts. I understand that you cannot have 2 MX records work at the same time, correct? Is there a way around this? Is this question clear? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your overall understanding of MX records is correct.  If you have more then 1 MX record (which is quite valid and common), MX records with lower number will be tried first, and MX records with the same priority will be tried in random order, but only until the mail is sent.

In order to set up dual mail delivery the primary MTA (ie mail server associated with the MX record) would need to split the incoming emails into 2 and redeliver them as desired (eg into 2 mail boxes or forward on to new addresses).

That said, if you were an end user, you might look at using IMAP, and getting Google to pull a copy of the emai from bluehost (I assume Bluehost offer IMAP) using the IMAP protocol.